# Two times html entity decode

Tags: php

Can somebody please explain me why I need to **html_entity_decode** the **$reversecaption**  two times to get the decoded characters?

Edit: $finalArray['Caption'] is pure text that comes from a XML file.

```
$reversecaption = html_entity_decode($finalArray['Caption'],ENT_QUOTES, "ISO8859-1");
$reversecaption = html_entity_decode($reversecaption,ENT_QUOTES, "ISO8859-1");
```

If I run it just once the characters stay encoded.

```
$reversecaption = html_entity_decode($finalArray['Caption'],ENT_QUOTES, "ISO8859-1");
```

I'm new to PHP so I'ld like to get that logic.

Comment: Please show some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no idea where your original data is coming from, but it was obviously double-encoded!

Double-encoded data looks like `&amp;amp;`, `&amp;quot;`, ...

Comment: Sorry, I added that information. `it was obviously double-encoded!` Argh, I didn't think of that. If I let it stay double-encoded - could that cause any further problems?

Comment: The problem is why is it double-encoded, and why are you trying to do exactly? Your question is not precise enough!